# Convert World File to latitude and longitude points

Tags: javascript, coordinates, converters

I have two files: `tl00sw.tfw` and `tl00sw.tiff`

`tl00sw.tiff` - it's a map

[image]

and file `tl00sw.tfw` contains:

`0.70402703463813 
0 
0 
-0.70402703463813 
500000 
205000`

And I need to convert this numbers to **lat and long** coordinates. 
I try to do it with this formula: 

`X geo location = line5 + Xpixels * line1 + Ypixels * line3
Y geo location = line6 + Ypixels * line4 + Xpixels * line2`

and I get numbers:
`x = 505000`
`y = 200000`

It's some type of [World File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file)

BTW - size of image is 7102x7102

Or maybe exists some converter on `JavaScript`

Comment: Looks like you need to get more information from the source of the file, but at a guess, it looks like it's using the OSGB36 grid, as your x/y correspond with the south eastern corner of TL00 (making that Bovingdon as the largest settlement on your map)

Comment: @RowlandShaw I can be whatever images and data. It's just example. Thanks for response

Comment: So what are you trying to do/having a problem with?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I need to put this images to Google Maps. I know how to put images, but I need to get real coordinates (lat, long) from `*.tfw` files. I'm building system where user upload this files and it automatically place image on right place on map

Comment: So you're going to need to reproject the image - there's an implementation at http://blogs.casa.ucl.ac.uk/2013/12/05/british-national-grid-transformation-and-reprojection-in-r/ or http://osgbwebmaptools.sourceforge.net/OSGBWebMapTools.html which should let you convert the OSGB co-ordinates (e.g. 505000, 200000) to WGS84 (again, e.g. 51.688947, -0.482423)

Comment: Better still, you could [do this in a GIS tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/16678/9)

Comment: @RowlandShaw I will try, thank you